# Vertically align image and text

Tags: html, css, css-float

How can I align image and text horizontally without moving the other text under the image

I like to do this (sample XXXXX is a big image)

```
XXXXXXXX  This is a big image.
XXXXXXXX  all text should not goes 
XXXXXXXX  down the image
XXXXXXXX
```

But the problem is my text went down the image

```
XXXXXXXX  This is a big image.
XXXXXXXX  
XXXXXXXX  
XXXXXXXX
all text should not goes down the image
```

Pls help me.

Here is my code

```
<div id = 'wrap'> 
   <div class='image'>
     <img src="/test/1.jpg" />
     This is a big image  all text should not goes down the image
   </div>
   <div class='image'>
     <img src="/test/2.jpg" />
     This is a big image  all text should not goes down the image
   </div>

</div>
```

CSS that I used...

```
#wrap {
   overflow: auto; 
   height: 300px; 
}

.image{ 
    border-top-style:outset;
}

#wrap > div > img {
    width : 80px;
     height : 70px;
     margin-left:5px;
     margin-top:5px;
     margin-bottom:5px;
     padding-bottom: 4px; 
     float:left;
    clear:left;
}
```

Comment: Either write a two column layour (picture | text), or just float the image to the left with a line of css: `float: left;`. This allows the text to use the space under the image if it is long enough.

Answer (score 6):

Just float the image to the left

```
img {
   float: left;
}
```

What happens after floating the image to the left is it will create an empty space on the right so that text will set the way you want.

> Note : Never forget to clear your floats...Also you might like to wrap this up inside a container div

Rest :

You could give class to an img you want to float so instead of using `img{float: left;}` you should use `img.class_name {float: left;}` so that it will target the image precisely, also you might like to wrap up the text inside `p` element as [Sam Carrington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1369911/sam-carrington) told you so that you could padd up the text and also style it...

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6j9E8/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="to_the_left" src="http://images.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif" />
    <p class="paragraph">Hi this is big long text I want to place it to the right of my image</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}

.to_the_left {
    float: left;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

p.paragraph {
    padding-top: 30px; /* You can set accordingly */
}
```

Comment: agh, beat me to it. You could also use `display: inline-block;`, but `float: left;` would be preferred.

Comment: tried to used float but the problem is all text goes down the image.. I edited my question so you can check the css that i used

Answer (score 0):

You should always contain the text in the div inside a semantic element - this will have the advantage of allowing you to target the text in a unique container using css.

```
<div class='image'>
  <img src="/test/1.jpg" />
  <p class="sidebar">This is a big image  all text should not goes down the image</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to used float but the problem is all text goes down the image

Answer (score 0):

```
#wrap .image img { float: left; width: 200px;}
```

Comment: tried to used float but the problem is all text goes down the image